# How to convert separate year and month column into a single date and get the difference between two dates in terms of months/days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

After joining two tables in google bigquery, I ended up with a table which have two sets of year and month in four separate columns. First two year and month columns should form one date and the second pair for another date. I need to convert each of those two sets of year and month in to two single dates, and then get the difference between those two dates in terms of months or days.

```
  Example of the table is provided below: 

       year    month    year    month
    0  2013     12      2014      2
    1  2014     5       2014      9
    2  2015     6       2015      8
```

If anyone can help code this in bigquery, would be really helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the difference in months, you don't need to convert to dates.  Just use arithmetic:

```
select (year1 * 12 + month1) - (year2 * 12 + month2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2013 year1, 12 month1, 2014 year2, 2 month2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2014, 5, 2014, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2015, 6, 2015, 8 
)
SELECT 
  DATE(year1, month1, 1) date1, 
  DATE(year2, month2, 1) date2,
  DATE_DIFF(DATE(year2, month2, 1), DATE(year1, month1, 1), DAY) diff_in_days
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row date1       date2       diff_in_days     
1   2013-12-01  2014-02-01  62   
2   2014-05-01  2014-09-01  123  
3   2015-06-01  2015-08-01  61
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the DATE(YEAR,MONTH,DAY) function two times passing the data that you've got on both columns and passing 1 as the day since it doesn't matter, then use DATE_DIFF(date_expression, date_expression, date_part) passing the dates that you got from those functions and the DATE PART that you want to get as a return, it accepts :
DAY,WEEK, ISOWEEK,MONTH,QUARTER,YEAR and ISOYEAR.